# Does Apple Provide default implementation of isEqual:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsobject

In C there is a default implementation of equality operator. Go through all the member and verify that they satisfy the equality operator. The default is somewhat stupid because if an object contains pointer then the equality operator of the member would be performed on the pointer.

Still, it's good enough for my purpose.

So does it?

Or are we expected to implement isEqual and the corresponding hash for everytime we create a custom object that may we want to use isequal for.

It seems to me the "default" implementation is to simply compare the pointer of the object and not it's member. Am I correct here? It's even worse than C++ standard comparison. That's what I want to verify.

It seems to me if our class is the immediate children of NSObject then isEqual will simply call it's parent's isEqual and that simply compare pointers.

Am I correct here? I am just wanting to make sure of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `NSObject` provides `isEqual:`, and all your objects are descendants of `NSObject`, then the the simple answer is that a default implementation is provided.

Now you are concerned over the algorithm this default uses, and in a comment write *"I wouldn't be sure simply by testing"*. Let's look at testing, just for fun ;-)

Now `isEqual:` is a rather fundamental method, if Apple decided to change its semantics the consequences could be significant and not good. So while Apple is free to change how it is implemented provided the *semantics* remain the same, which means the same objects compare equal after the change as before. Now you've mentioned three possible algorithms `isEqual:` could use:

1. Pointer comparison - is it the *exact same* object
2. Shallow comparison - do the fields of the object have the same value compared directly
3. Deep comparison - do the non-pointer-valued fields compared directly have the same value, and do the pointer-valued fields compare equal using `isEqual:`

These all have different semantics, whichever one Apple has chosen it can't change without breaking a lot of code. And different semantics means you can test...

Coding as I type, errors expected! Only important bits included:

```
@implementation A

- (BOOL) isEqual:(id)other
{
   NSLog(@"A.isEqual called");
   return self == other; // true iff same object
}

@end

@interface B

@property (readwrite) int anInteger;
@property (readwrite) A *anA;

@end

@implementation B

@synthesize anInteger, anA;

@end

// Let's test the algorithm

A *myA = [A new];
B *bOne = [B new];
B *bTwo = [B new];

bOne.anInteger = 42;
bOne.anA = myA;

bTwo.anInteger = 42;
bTwo.anA = myA;

// What output is produced (all of it!)
NSLog(@"[bOne isEqual:bTwo] -> %@", [bOne isEqual:bTwo] ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

HTH a little.

Comment: To test apple's default implementation you must not implement one your self and see if it works. I guess it's obvious by now that it's not even documented and shouldn't be count on at all. +1

Comment: If you actually test it for fun I'll select this one as the answer. I just want to move on to other things as it's obviously not documented and can't be relied on.

Comment: @HaryantoCiu - The only logical choice as the default is pointer comparison, that is what `NSObject`'s `equalTo` uses, and it is documented - though not obviously (e.g. see <http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introspection/Introspection.html>). I was suggesting you can test and rely on the result.

Comment: Yap pointer comparison. Not even members' pointer comparison. I suppose IOS will simply call [super isEqual] like usual and if the super is NSObject, then it'll just do pointer comparison because NSObject do not know the iVar of it's children.

Answer (score 2):

I think that `NSObject`’s implementation does pointer comparison, and various other classes from the SDK do what’s most appropriate, ie. `NSString` does comparison on string contents, `NSArray` compares content equality, and so on. If you want to have “better” equality defined for your custom objects, you have to decide about the semantics and implement it yourself.

Comment: I just want to be sure. I wouldn't be sure simply by testing. Also the answers often come up with references, etc. The apple references tell nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Its a little confusing because of the way Apple separates their docs between protocols and interfaces.

```
@protocol NSObject

- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object;
```

This is a required method to be implemented so NSObject (the class) definitely implements this although you wouldnt know it from looking at the class definition on apples dev site. This is directly from the headers in xcode.

In general without implementing a custom isEqual you will expect to only get pointer identity and thats ok in many cases.  Systems need to be designed around the way you identify unique instances regardless of the peculiarity of a particular feature such as hash and isEqual.  If you need to test for object equality beyond the pointer then you just have to do that.

Comment: Pointer of the object or pointers of the members? That is the question.